# Can I turn my Android device into a webcam?

Tags: wi-fi, usb, camera, usb-connection-mode, webcam

If so, how? Could it be implemented via a USB, Bluetooth or Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: Specifically for USB: [How do I turn my Android into a USB Webcam?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159274/how-do-i-turn-my-android-into-a-usb-webcam/159278#159278)

Answer (score 10):

[IP Webcam](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ip-webcam/com.pas.webcam) (Turns your phone into a network camera with multiple viewing options.)

(alternate direct [link](http://ip-webcam.appspot.com/))

EDIT: fixed link

Comment: It worked as a regular webcam when used in conjunction with this software http://ip-webcam.appspot.com/

Answer (score 4):

Droidcam is supposed to do it over wifi. Qik is a good option if you don't need a computer in the loop.

Comment: Currently Droidcam works only for desktop applications. It won't work for Flash.

Comment: http://qik.com/ Record and instantly share videos from your mobile phone, Share live video two-ways from one mobile phone to another

Comment: Qik is dead https://blogs.skype.com/2016/02/22/skype-qik-is-moving/

Answer (score 3):

[Justin.tv](http://blog.justin.tv/justintv-android/) just came out with an Android app to do video streaming.

It uses any data connection you have, but the faster/more reliable the connection the better quality you will get.

Comment: While it cannot be used in every way a webcam does, it will cover some of its functions.

Comment: justin.tv is now known as twitch.tv

Answer (score 1):

I've had very good performance from Qik. It can also buffer your video, so if your 3G/4G connection is bad, it will upload later when you have a better signal. WiFi is of course also supported, very simple, very quick ;-)

Comment: I think Qik is more similar to the `share with Youtube` Gallery function, than Droidcam