# How to use an android phone as a wireless webcam?

Tags: camera, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I turn my Android device into a webcam?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/can-i-turn-my-android-device-into-a-webcam)

Is it possible? It is possible with nokia symbian phone using an Motvik's app [wwigo](http://www.symbian-freak.com/news/007/06/wwigo_webcam_wherever_i_go.htm). I am wondering whether a similar app exists for android.