# How do I turn my Android into a USB Webcam?

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, webcam

I can turn it into an IP Webcam fairly easily using a myriad of apps + iSpy on the desktop.

However, even with 2 gigabit wifi, framerate seems unreasonably poor. Therefore, I would like to plug in my USB cable and stream it (DisplayLink can stream 4k over USB, so it must be possible in theory)

This would save me from spending hundreds of dollars on yet another camera. 4k video is supported by my Samsung S6, and that would be amazing to be able to use as a webcam.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a way using USB debugging support on the Android. The steps are quite involved, but here they are: http://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/connect/

Careful, your phone can overheat when doing this for awhile. Also keep in mind that 4k is not supported, just 1080p. Both on Wifi & on USB the framerate alternates between super fast (>30fps), and super slow (<4fps) in both OBS & iSpy. Not sure why. I think it's the app since native video recording works.

I'm going to do native recording and use a clapping trick to sync audio between an external mic and the internal one from here on out.

Comment: It still work rather well today. TY

Comment: Anyone try this over USB-C? Does it work better? I was on USB 3.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Iriun 4K Webcam for PC and Mac](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jacksoftw.webcam) (gratis for basic features) to use your Android phone's camera as a wireless or USB webcam in Microsoft Windows, macOS 10.12+ and Ubuntu 18.04+.

It supports resolutions up to 4K. (Max resolution depends on the phone).

---

Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10:

[image]

Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (go to https://iriun.com/ to get the program):

[image]

The instructions are straightforward:

[image]