# Turn Android device into a wireless or USB webcam with background removal

Tags: usb, camera, privacy, webcam, video-conference

There exist [several applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1159/12202) such as [DroidCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam&hl=en_US) that  can turn one's Android device into a wireless or [USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159274/12202) webcam.

Do any of these applications have a background removal feature (= only shows the human face/upper body that appears on the video)? I tried DroidCam but it doesn't seem to have this feature.