# How to use Pixel 6 as webcam on Android 14?

Tags: google-pixel-6, webcam, android-14

Many reports in the tech press said that Android 14 would include an option to use Android phones as a webcam when connected to another device over USB.

Here it is mentioned on the official [Android 14 website](https://www.android.com/android-14/)

[image]

Upon installing Android 14 on my Pixel 6, I don't see this option. It's supposed to come up on the USB menu when you plug in the phone.

I contacted Google Support as a Google One user, but they were useless as usual - hadn't even heard of the feature.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Sidenote: Google One is not a part of the Android team. So, it should be understandable that they don't know about latest Android features other than their Google products.

Comment: Related questions, independent of the Android version: [Can I turn my Android device into a webcam?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1159/44325), [How do I turn my Android into a USB Webcam?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159274/44325)

Comment: It's there now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature should/will be available in December feature drop (also known as Android 14 QPR1), not Android 14 release that just started rollout.

So you either need to install a Beta OS or wait for a couple of months for it to rollout.

When that happens, you'll plug in the phone into your computer via USB cable, tap the "Charging this device via USB" notification and select webcam as the option.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's what "you can **soon** use your Android phone as a beautiful webcam" means!