# Use my Android phone as the camera and microphone for PowerPoint slide recording

Tags: microphone, webcam

For conference purpose, I have to record a PowerPoint presentation recording. (That is, I have to record a video of me explaining a PowerPoint presentation using the webcam and mic while playing the presentayion). The problem is that the inbuilt camera and microphone of my laptop are not that great. iS there any way to use my android phone as the source of the camera and mic input? I tried DroidCam and I could connect the camera to the laptop. But when I start recording, it is using the default inbuilt camera instead of my phone.

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S9 running on android 10.

Comment: FYI for alternate solutions: [Can I turn my Android device into a webcam?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1159/3573) However you don't explain how you record so the problem/limitations may be with that PC software.

Comment: If you don't manager to change the recording software to use DroidCam you can try to disable the inbuilt camera of your PC, e.g. if it is a Windows PC in the DeviceManager.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion there is an option inside the PowerPoint where you can select the source of audio and video. You can select droidcam there.